# How to get indexOf of multidimentional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having some troubles getting the indexOf a multidimentional array.

```
var z = [["231f20", 5385], ["ffffff", 2419], ["ffafff", 2419]];
var index = z[0].indexOf('ffffff');
alert(index); #returns -1
```

As you can observe, the hex value and numbers (pixel quantity) are inside the same list in `z`.

How can I filter and get the indexOf the correct list ?

Comment: What index do you want? 1? (1, 0)?

Comment: You need to flatten the array to search for the contents of inner arrays, or use a recursive method to do that.

Comment: `"ffffff"` isn't in `z[0]` in any case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I filter and get the indexOf the correct list ?

You *could* use `filter`, but I wouldn't; I'd use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)*:

```js
var z = [["231f20", 5385], ["ffffff", 2419], ["ffafff", 2419]];
var index = z.findIndex(function(entry) {
  return entry.indexOf("ffffff") != -1;
});
console.log(index);
```

`findIndex` returns the index of the first entry for which your callback returned a truthy value.

That just tells you the outer index (1). If you wanted **both** indexes, I'd probably use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)** and have the callback close over the result variables:

```js
var z = [["231f20", 5385], ["ffffff", 2419], ["ffafff", 2419]];
var outerIndex, innerIndex;
var index = z.some(function(entry, index) {
  var n = entry.indexOf("ffffff");
  if (n != -1) {
    outerIndex = index;
    innerIndex = n;
    return true;
  }
});
console.log(outerIndex, innerIndex);
```

---

* `findIndex` was added in ES2015, but it's trivial to polyfill; see the linked MDN article for a polyfill.

** `some` is from ES5 back in 2009, so it'll be on everything but truly obsolete browsers like IE8. Also polyfillable.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a quick and dirty deep indexOf function which returns an array of indices to follow:

```
Object.prototype.deepIndexOf = Array.prototype.deepIndexOf = function (v) {
    for (var i in this) {
        if (this[i] === v) {
            return [i];
        }

        if ('object' === typeof this[i]) {
            var t = this[i].deepIndexOf(v);
            if (t !== undefined) {
                t.unshift(i);
                return t;
            }
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}
```

This probably fails in some cases, but works for simple arrays and objects:

```js
Object.prototype.deepIndexOf = Array.prototype.deepIndexOf = function(v) {
 for(var i in this) {
   if(this[i] === v) {
     return [i];
    }

    if('object' === typeof this[i]) {
     var t = this[i].deepIndexOf(v);
      if(t !== undefined) {
       t.unshift(i);
       return t;
      }
    }
  }
  return undefined;
}

var z = [["231f20", 5385], ["ffffff", 2419], ["ffafff", 2419]];

var z2 = {
 hello: {
   world: 5
  },
  bye: {
   world: 3,
    earth: 4
  }
}

console.log(z.deepIndexOf('ffffff'));
console.log(z2.deepIndexOf(4));

// And even very deep objects/arrays:

var verydeep = {
    one: {
        two: [
            [
                {
                    five: {
                        six: [
                            'Hello'
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
}

console.log(verydeep.deepIndexOf('Hello'))
```

Outputs:

```
[
  "1",
  "0"
]
[
  "bye",
  "earth"
]
[
  "one",
  "two",
  "0",
  "0",
  "five",
  "six",
  "0"
]
```

Comment: Cool, but **never** add enumerable properties to `Object.prototype` or `Array.prototype` as you are above. (Adding *anything* to `Object.prototype` is probably a bad idea, even if non-enumerable.) Use `Object.defineProperty` to add non-enumerables instead.